# ASP com SQL trazendo resultado diferente da consulta

Tags: sql, asp

Boa tarde!

Estamos finalizando um painel que trará os resultados de um SQL numa página ASP. Já temos dois paineis finalizados que estão puxando os resultados perfeitamente. Apenas um dos paineis não traz o resultado com o SELECT que usamos, embora quando jogado no SQL SERVER retorna o valor correto. Apenas no ASP rodando que não. Tentamos algumas alternativas, porém nada. Segue trecho do código:

```
strSQL =          " SELECT count(solid) AS ENCERRADOS "
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM SOLICITACAO S "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN USUARIO U ON (S.UsuIdReclamante  = U.UsuID) "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN FilhoPai f on u.usuid = f.UsuIDFilho "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN Usuario ux on ux.UsuID = f.UsuIDPai "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN Usuario ur on ur.UsuID = s.UsuIDResponsavel "
strSQL = strSQL & " INNER JOIN Usuario ug on ur.usuIDGrupo = ug.usuID "
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE SolData BETWEEN '2015-07-16 00:00:00' and '2015-07-16 23:59:59' "
strSQL = strSQL & " AND ug.usunome = 'Service Desk - 1º Nível TI' "
strSQL = strSQL & " AND s.usuidultimoresp = '2721184' "
strSQL = strSQL & " AND (SOLSTATUS IN ('7','9')) "

Set BUSCA3 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
BUSCA3.Open strSQL, Conexao, 1
```

E o local onde é exibido o resultado:

```
<p class="textoPainel"><%= BUSCA3("ENCERRADOS")%></p>
```

Na consulta direto no banco, retorna 22 o valor. No ASP retorna 0.

Comment: A conexão utilizada na página e o banco apontada na aplicação é a mesma que do banco de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estou acostumando com linguagem PHP, mas já mexi em ASP clássico, seu eu me lembro, era algo parecido com isso:

```
<p class="textoPainel">
<%
if not BUSCA3.eof and not BUSCA3.bof then
    response.write(BUSCA3.fields("ENCERRADOS").value)
    BUSCA3.close
end if
%>
</p>
```

ou

```
<p class="textoPainel"><%=BUSCA3.Fields("ENCERRADOS").Value; %></p>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda de todos! Conseguimos finalizar aqui o problema. Caso interesse à alguém, o problema estava nos INNER JOIN! Quando retiramos, ficou OK.